# add default option to angularjs select

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to add a default option to a select with angular but it adds a blank option which strangely disappears when I select it.

I am getting the object to bind to the select using `ng-options` like this.  I am appending a default option like this:

```
var DocumentSearchController = function (documentsService) {
    documentsService.getDocTypes().then(function (results) {
        this.documentTypes = results.data;
        this.documentTypes.unshift({ DocumentTypeID: null, Name: 'Select a Document Type' });
    }.bind(this));
```

The structure of the objects is:

```
[{DocumentTypeID: 1, Name: 'Blah'}]
```

I then use `ng-options` to bind the objects:

```
<select class="form-control"
        id="documentTypeSelector"
        name="documentTypeSelector"
        ng-model="vm.selectedDocumentType"
        ng-options="option.Name for option in vm.documentTypes | orderBy: 'option.DocumentTypeID':false track by option.DocumentTypeID">
</select>
```

Then annoying this is that a blank option is strangely added that is removed when I select an item.

The options are also not ordered so I suspect my list comprehension is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an default value this way :

```
<select class="form-control"
        id="documentTypeSelector"
        name="documentTypeSelector"
        ng-model="vm.selectedDocumentType"
        ng-options="option.Name for option in vm.documentTypes | orderBy: 'option.DocumentTypeID':false track by option.DocumentTypeID">
    <option value="">Select a Document Type</option>
</select>
```

**Edit** Or using init function

```
<select class="form-control"
        ng-init="vm.selectedDocumentType= vm.documentTypes[0]" 
        id="documentTypeSelector"
        name="documentTypeSelector"
        ng-model="vm.selectedDocumentType"
        ng-options="option.Name for option in vm.documentTypes | orderBy:'option.DocumentTypeID':false track by option.DocumentTypeID">
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

To define a default `<select>` element just assign to `ng-model` binded variable a default value available in one `<option>` element (or value).

In your case `vm.selectedDocumentType` should be set to a `vm.documentTypes[theIndexYouChoose].DocumentTypeID`

More in general a simplified example could be

```
// given $scope.options = [1, 2, 3];
<select ng-init="selectedOption=1" ng-option="option for option in options" ng-model='selectedOption'>
</select>
```

You will find no empty options and the selected option will be 1